# How do I update a batch of S3 objects' metadata using ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fog

I need to change some metadata (Content-Type) on hundreds or thousands of objects on S3. What's a good way to do this with ruby? As far as I can tell there is no way to save only metadata with [fog.io](http://fog.io), the entire object must be re-saved. Seems like using [the official sdk library](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ruby) would require me rolling a wrapper environment just for this one task.

Answer (score 7):

You're right, the official SDK lets you modify the object metadata without uploading it again. What it does is [copy the object](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/lib/aws/s3/s3_object.rb#L488) but that's on the server so you don't need to download the file and re-upload it.

A wrapper would be easy to implement, something like

```
bucket.objects.each do |object|
  object.metadata['content-type'] = 'application/json'
end
```

Comment: More discussion of this here: http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-fog/browse_thread/thread/e632fc61405bf04c

Comment: this adds only metadata with x-amz-meta- prefix. is the any way of adding just a normal Content-Type metadata?

Answer (score 5):

In the v2 API, you can use `Object#copy_from()` or `Object.copy_to()` with the `:metadata` and `:metadata_directive => 'REPLACE'` options to update an object's metadata without downloading it from S3.

The code in [Joost's gist](https://gist.github.com/joost/94963b74c5b03b2b752f) throws this error:

> Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidRequest: This copy request is illegal because
>   it is trying to copy an object to itself without changing the object's
>   metadata, storage class, website redirect location or encryption
>   attributes.

This is because by default AWS ignores the `:metadata` supplied with a copy operation because it copies metadata. We must set the `:metadata_directive => 'REPLACE'` option if we want to update the metadata in-place.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#copy_from-instance_method

Here's a full, working code snippet that I recently used to perform metadata update operations:

```
require 'aws-sdk'

# S3 setup boilerplate
client = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  :region => 'us-east-1',
  :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY'], 
)
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(:client => client)

# Get an object reference
object = s3.bucket('my-bucket-name').object('my-object/key')

# Create our new metadata hash. This can be any hash; in this example we update
# existing metadata with a new key-value pair.
new_metadata = object.metadata.merge('MY_NEW_KEY' => 'MY_NEW_VALUE')

# Use the copy operation to replace our metadata
object.copy_to(object,
  :metadata => new_metadata,

  # IMPORTANT: normally S3 copies the metadata along with the object.
  # we must supply this directive to replace the existing metadata with
  # the values we supply
  :metadata_directive => "REPLACE",
)
```

For easy re-use:

```
def update_metadata(s3_object, new_metadata = {})
  s3_object.copy_to(s3_object,
    :metadata => new_metadata
    :metadata_directive => "REPLACE"
  )
end
```

Comment: To add cache control use: object.copy_to(object, cache_control: 'public,max-age=333333', metadata_directive: 'REPLACE')

Comment: The V3 API does not seem to support this anymore, I think the copy_from in v3 maybe only does metadata copy, does not allow replace? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#copy_from-instance_method

Answer (score 4):

For future readers, here's a complete sample of changing stuff using the Ruby aws-sdk v1 (also see this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/joost/94963b74c5b03b2b752f) for a aws-sdk v2 sample):

```
# Using v1 of Ruby aws-sdk as currently v2 seems not able to do this (broken?).
require 'aws-sdk-v1'

key = YOUR_AWS_KEY
secret = YOUR_AWS_SECRET
region = YOUR_AWS_REGION

AWS.config(access_key_id: key, secret_access_key: secret, region: region)
s3 = AWS::S3.new
bucket = s3.buckets[bucket_name]
bucket.objects.with_prefix('images/').each do |obj|
  puts obj.key
  # Add  metadata: {} to next line for more metadata.
  obj.copy_from(obj.key, content_type: obj.content_type, cache_control: 'max-age=1576800000',  acl: :public_read)
end
```

Comment: Your Gist says the v2 sample doesn't seem to work, and suggests it might be a bug in the SDK... I take it you haven't yet resolved it?

Comment: Nope. Just try the gist with the latest version of v2 :)

Comment: v2 version doesn't work for me either. I've commented the gist with my solution (re-up-loading each file).

Answer (score 3):

after some search this seems to work for me

```
obj.copy_to(obj, :metadata_directive=>"REPLACE", :acl=>"public-read",:content_type=>"text/plain")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the sdk to change the content type will result in `x-amz-meta-`  prefix. My solution was to use ruby + aws cli. This will directly write to the `content-type` instead of `x-amz-meta-content-type`.

```
ids_to_copy = all_object_ids
ids_to_copy.each do |id|
    object_key = "#{id}.pdf"
    command = "aws s3 cp s3://{bucket-name}/#{object_key} s3://{bucket-name}/#{object_key} --no-guess-mime-type --content-type='application/pdf' --metadata-directive='REPLACE'"
    system(command)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This API appears to be available now:

```
Fog::Storage.new({
  :provider                 => 'AWS',
  :aws_access_key_id        => 'foo',
  :aws_secret_access_key    => 'bar',
  :endpoint => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/',
  :path_style => true
}).put_object_tagging(
  'bucket_name',
  's3_key',
  {foo: 'bar'}
)
```